# Javascript: I Want to Refresh The Page With The Changed Code Structure (Value Fields) According to The Values User Provided

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a "save page as PDF" button on my page. This button only saves according to the page's code structure. So, the values which users have provided after the page's loading doesn't count.

Form fields contain input areas: (1) Values brought from previous calculation page with cookies (read-only) (2) Values those users can add / change

When user clicks on the **"SAVE (pdf)"** button, I want the page to be refreshed with the **new structure**; value sections of the inputs are changed, according to the new values standing in the input fields, then firing the "SAVE AS PDF" button.

How this can be technically possible. I couldn't figure it out. I appreciate your help very much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Renal Dose</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<link rel="manifest" href="../img/favicons/manifest.json">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JQuery-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form class="border border-light p-5 print" name="saveList" action="/en/print" onsubmit="submit();">
  <div class="form-row justify-content-lg-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 mt-3" id="timey">Calculation Time:<br>
      <input class="form-control" id="time" type="text" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 mt-3" id="namey">Patient Name:<br>
      <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 mt-3" id="wardy">Ward Name:<br>
      <input class="form-control" id="ward" type="text" name="ward">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 mt-3" id="docty">Doctor Name:<br>
      <input class="form-control" id="doctor" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 mt-3" id="crCly">Creatinine Clearance (ml/min):<br>
      <input class="form-control" id="crCl" type="number" autocomplete="off" value="" readonly="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 mt-3" id="diay">State of Hemodialysis:<br>
      <input class="form-control" id="dia" type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 mt-3" id="acty">Active Substance:<br>
      <input class="form-control" id="actSubs" type="text" autocomplete="off" required="" readonly="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 mt-3" id="producty">Brand Name:<br>
      <input class="form-control" id="productName" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 mt-3" id="suggesty">Suggested Dose:<br>
      <input class="form-control" id="suggest" type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 mt-3" id="operaty">Operator:<br>
      <input class="form-control" id="operator" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 mt-3" id="noty">Notes:<br>
      <input class="form-control" id="notes" type="text" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-justify justify-content-center mt-5">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
      <p><strong>Note: </strong>All the information above is advisory for the full authorized health professionals who has enough capability for determination of patient's treatment. And they can never be a substitute for the information and applications
        of physicians, pharmacists or other health professionals those will provide optimum benefit for the patient.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="row text-center justify-content-center my-5">
  <p class="text-center mt-5">
    <a href="http://pdf-ace.com/pdfme?cache=0" class="btn btn-danger">Save as PDF</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mulgey/t6dmvr4s/8/

Comment: Some general ideas: Send the form via javascript, encode whatever you need into the url and restore it from there (javascript or serverside)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely, but have you looked into storing the variables in the `localStorage`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @dev When users reach this page from the previous calculation page, results are copied to the fields automatically, by using “cookies”. If localStorage works the same way (adding information without changing the source code, (<input value=“valueToBeChanged” ...) it won’t work again

Comment: dear @BennoStraub, restoring from url, makes my code structure changed? eg. <input value=""...> to <input value="newValue"..>